# Is there anything in the standard for Open ID Connect to terminate a session?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Is there a standard mechanism in Open ID Connect to kill an active session?
Say a client has an Access token set to expire in 2 minutes. Someone from a central location logs the user out. The idea to prevent that access token from being viable on the very next request as opposed to when the token expires.

Answer (score 0):

This would require Web APIs to contact the authorization server on every single request, which would cause performance problems.

It is standard to use short lived access tokens as the best middle ground. Most commonly this is around 30 or 60 minutes by default.

When reviewing OAuth behaviour in areas like this it can be worth comparing to older systems:

- It was never possible to revoke cookies in the manner you describe - so security is not made worse by using OAuth 2.0 based solutions

Typically it is possible to centrally revoke refresh tokens though, so that the next token refresh requires a new login.

Comment: The spec does define introspection as en endpoint that can be used on every request (in higher security scenarios). Assuming that endpoint (on the STS) is already getting hit for every request it wouldn't be a big leap to keep a blacklist of tokens in memory.

Comment: True - introspection is usually accompanied by result caching. If you have particular operations that are high security and not too frequent that could make sense. It would depend on the Authorization Server having usable options to revoke access tokens (as well as refresh tokens).

Comment: Out of interest I tend to prefer introspection architecturally as described in [my post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims) and to cache results as in [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts). You could maybe implement something similar and write some code to opt high security requests out of the caching.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of drafts that are helpful depending on your specific implementation:

- https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html
- https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html
- https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html

Several OIDC products are using these methods currently:

- https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/6/oidc1-guide/#openam-openid-session-management
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_oidc_session_mgmt_endpoint.html
- Several Others also.